# What's the rule on walking on Jewish graves?

Tags: cemetery-grave

Please provide reference to scriptures (Exact book, Chapter and page number), a synagogue has confirmed walking on graves is not allowed but couldn't provide any reference.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38561/in-a-cemetery-when-there-is-a-headstone-what-is-the-law-or-custom-of-walking-o

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya akbar  Just a comment, Jewish law is not always found implicitly in scriptures, but more often in the Shulchan Aruch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One source that brings this prohibition is [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 199:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.199.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אָסוּר לִדְרוֹךְ עַל גַבֵּי קְבָרִים, מִשּׁוּם דְּיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים,
>   דְּאָסוּר בַּהֲנָאָה. וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם אִם צָרִיךְ לְאֵיזֶה קֶבֶר
>   וְאֵין לוֹ דֶרֶךְ אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן יִדְרוֹךְ עַל גַבֵּי קְבָרִים,
>   מֻתָּר.
>
> It is forbidden to step upon graves because some Poskim maintain that
>   it is forbidden to derive benefit from them. However, if you have to
>   visit a certain grave, and have no way of getting there unless you
>   step upon other graves, it is permitted.